# Xamarin Forms Android - crash while taking photo without exception

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, media, photo

Xamarin Forms Android crashes while taking photo without exception. But this happens in like 65% of tries. Sometimes app doesn't crash and I can take photo normally. On other phone(same model) application crashes every time I want to take photo.

I'm using https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin like this:

```
if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable)
        {
            DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");
            return;
        }

        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Directory = "Sample",
            Name = "testPO.jpg"
        });

        if (file == null)
            return;

        DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");
```

Camera loads without problem, but when I press "Take photo" button application crashes and debugging in Visual Studio stops without any exception.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What version of android is there on your phone?  Is this on an emulatoror?

Comment: @JordyDieltjens Android version 6.0.1. No it's real device > Samsung SM-G900F Galaxy S5

Comment: It might be a permission issue, do you have a device ( perhaps simulator ) with version 5?

Comment: What do you mean with "device with version 5"?

Permissions:


     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: I ment 5.1 (lollipop). Did you add these permission yourself? If I remember correctly the plugin does that for you.

Comment: You might get some conflicts: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/247

Comment: Version of my device is 6.0.1 (Marshmallow). I thought I did it myself. But does this issue make sense when application crashes just sometimes? And Visual Studio stops debugging without any exception?

Comment: U should take a look at ur device log than (view - other windows - device logs) and than select ur device, normally you should find the error here

Comment: Brillant @JordyDieltjens ! I wasn't aware of this view and I found this entry: This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  
The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription key with a string value explaining 
to the user how the app uses this data. 
I've set SaveToAlbum to True and forgot to add this to info.plist. Many thanks!!!

Comment: @K232 i'm happy it helped you ;)

Comment: If an error is not handled as an exception, it will be written in output. So look there for more information

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is old but in case someone stumbles across this issue in the future:
I've had this issue and it ended up being the `NoHistory` flag in `MainActivity.cs` being set to `true`.

Remove `NoHistory = true` or set `NoHistory = false` to avoid the crash.

eg:

```
[Activity(Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, NoHistory = false)]
public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I've been stuck for hours and you just saved my day!
Cheers mate!

Comment: @MarkReimer Glad I could help :)