# Xamarin Android Camera sporadically crashes(returns to start page) after activating default android camera

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-camera

I have an Xamarin.Forms project that I have built for Android devices. The App inconsistently crashes when attempting to take a photo. It actually (incorrectly) returns to the start page when trying to return to the last page open (rather than fully crashing). I have included some errors that I found in my debug output (included below). I have also inlcuded my MainActvity.cs. Take Photo function from code, AppManifest and App.cs. I'm thinking that it might have something to do with a conflict with google map api library? but really I don't have a clue (have been struggling with this issue for 2 weeks). Any help greatly appreciated.

Errors from debug output

[libEGL] EGLNativeWindowType 0xba83d808 disconnect failed
...
[libEGL] EGLNativeWindowType 0xb0644808 disconnect failed
...
[SurfaceView] windowStopped(true) false com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.at{e04ff1 VFE...C.. ........ 0,0-1164,900}

MainActivity.cs

```
using System;
using TCmInsp;`
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using SQLite;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Acr.UserDialogs;
using Plugin.Media;
using Xamarin.Forms;`
```

```
namespace TCmInsp.Droid
{
        [Activity(Label = "TCmInsp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
            {

        protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            UserDialogs.Init(this);

            DependencyService.Register<DeleFromFile>();

            DependencyService.Get<DeleFromFile>();

            string fileName = "TCmInsp_db.db3";
            string folderPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string completePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath,fileName);

            LoadApplication(new App(completePath));

        }
                public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
                    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

AppManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.2" package="com.companyname.TCmInsp" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="29" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="TCmInsp.Android" android:largeHeap="true">
        <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" 
         android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" 
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="XXXX" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

App.cs

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Microsoft.AppCenter;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TCmInsp
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static string FilePath;
        //TODO: Replace with *.azurewebsites.net url after deploying backend to Azure
        //To debug on Android emulators run the web backend against .NET Core not IIS
        //If using other emulators besides stock Google images you may need to adjust the IP address
        //public static string AzureBackendUrl =
            //DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ? "http://10.0.2.2:5000" : "http://localhost:5000";
        //public static bool UseMockDataStore = true;


        public App(string filePath)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //if (UseMockDataStore)
            //    DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
            //else
            //    DependencyService.Register<AzureDataStore>();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Menu());
            FilePath = filePath;
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            AppCenter.Start("android=c2d7e90f-e58a-4009-8906-552bc4fbd4e5;" +
            "uwp=a95e94f1-4f1e-47a0-a397-d753f9f8e2aa;" +
            "ios={Your iOS App secret here}",
            typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
            
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {

        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
           
        }

    }
}
```

TakePhoto Function

```
private async void TakePhoto()
        {
            try
            {
                string gID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                string fN = "RI-" + Asset_ID.Text + lblUniqueName.Text + ".jpg";

                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("No Camera", "No camera available", "OK");
                    return;
                }

                await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
                var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

                if (current != NetworkAccess.Internet)
                {
                    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                    {
                        Directory = "Photos_for_Upload " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                        Name = fN,
                        SaveToAlbum = true
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                    {
                        Directory = "All_Photos",
                        Name = fN,
                        SaveToAlbum = true
                    });

                    //! added using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
                    var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=XXXX");
                    var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                    var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("tasman");

                    var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fN);

                    if (file == null)
                        return;
                    {
                        MainImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => file.GetStream());
                        await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file.GetStream());
                    }
                    await DisplayAlert("Successful", "Photo Saved", "OK");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Unsuccessful", "Photo Upload not working, Photo saved to Device", "OK");
            }
        }
```

Complete content of debug output

```
[Counters] exceeded sample count in FrameTime
[ViewRootImpl@a293eaf[MainActivity]] ViewPostIme pointer 0
[ViewRootImpl@a293eaf[MainActivity]] ViewPostIme pointer 1
[InputMethodManager] HSIFW - flag : 0
[DecorView] [INFO] isPopOver=false, config=true
[DecorView] updateCaptionType >> DecorView@4990f64[], isFloating=false, isApplication=true, hasWindowDecorCaption=false, hasWindowControllerCallback=true
[DecorView] setCaptionType = 0, this = DecorView@4990f64[]
[InputTransport] Input channel constructed: '30a014 ', fd=140
[ViewRootImpl@988101[IntermediateActivity]] setView = com.android.internal.policy.DecorView@4990f64 TM=true
[SurfaceControl] assignNativeObject: nativeObject = 0 Surface(name=null)/@0x36ba6 / android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1117 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1820 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9005 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3360 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9971 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1010 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks:809 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame:744 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run:995 
[ViewRootImpl@988101[IntermediateActivity]] Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1200,1920) new=(0,0,1200,1920) req=(1200,1920)0 dur=12 res=0x7 s={true 2959354880} ch=true fn=-1
[ViewRootImpl@988101[IntermediateActivity]] [DP] dp(1) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.reportNextDraw:10957 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3845 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 
[ViewRootImpl@988101[IntermediateActivity]] [DP] pd() Asnyc report
[ViewRootImpl@988101[IntermediateActivity]] [DP] pdf(0) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.lambda$performDraw$1$ViewRootImpl:4668 android.view.-$$Lambda$ViewRootImpl$DJd0VUYJgsebcnSohO6h8zc_ONI.run:6 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:938 
[ViewRootImpl@988101[IntermediateActivity]] [DP] rdf()
[ViewRootImpl@a293eaf[MainActivity]] MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
[libprocessgroup] set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
[libprocessgroup] set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject s[3130614784]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject e[3130614784]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject s[3130617632]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject e[3130617632]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject s[3130617568]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject e[3130617568]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject s[3130617696]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject e[3130617696]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject s[3004402752]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject e[3004402752]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject s[3004402880]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject e[3004402880]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject s[2959468480]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject e[2959468480]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject s[2959468928]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject e[2959468928]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject s[2959468768]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject e[2959468768]
[AbsListView]  in onLayout changed 
[SurfaceView] setParentSpaceRectangle: useBLAST = false position = Rect(19, 1335 - 1183, 2235) frameNumber = 58 t = android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@f359f88
[SurfaceView] applySurfaceTransforms: t = android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@f359f88 surfaceControl = Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.companyname.TCmInsp/crc64ceabadbfeeee2420.MainActivity@e04ff1@4)/@0xff52ceb frame = 58
[SurfaceView] applySurfaceTransforms: postScaleX = 1.0 postScaleY = 1.0
[InputTransport] Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=141
[ViewRootImpl@988101[IntermediateActivity]] stopped(true) old=false
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject s[3094087232]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject e[3094087232]
[View] requestLayout() improperly called by crc64720bb2db43a66fe9.NavigationPageRenderer{4e5565c V.E...... ........ 0,0-1200,1848 #1} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject s[3130614144]
[libEGL] EGLNativeWindowType 0xb0642c08 disconnect failed
[SurfaceControl] assignNativeObject: nativeObject = 0 Surface(name=null)/@0x3fab7cb / android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1117 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1810 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9005 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3360 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9971 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1010 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks:809 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame:744 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run:995 
[SurfaceControl] assignNativeObject: nativeObject = 0 Surface(name=null)/@0x36ba6 / android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1117 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1820 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9005 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3360 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9971 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1010 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks:809 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame:744 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run:995 
[ViewRootImpl@988101[IntermediateActivity]] Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1200,1920) new=(0,0,1200,1920) req=(1200,1920)8 dur=11 res=0x5 s={false 0} ch=false fn=-1
[SurfaceView] onWindowVisibilityChanged(8) false com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.at{e04ff1 VFE...C.. ........ 0,0-1164,900} of ViewRootImpl@a293eaf[MainActivity]
[SurfaceView] surfaceDestroyed callback.size 1 #2 com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.at{e04ff1 VFE...C.. ........ 0,0-1164,900}
[libEGL] EGLNativeWindowType 0xba83d808 disconnect failed
[SurfaceView] remove() from RT android.view.SurfaceView$2@1746026 Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.companyname.TCmInsp/crc64ceabadbfeeee2420.MainActivity@e04ff1@4)/@0xff52ceb
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject s[3130614016]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject e[3130614016]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject s[3130613856]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject e[3130613856]
[libEGL] EGLNativeWindowType 0xb0644808 disconnect failed
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject s[3130613792]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject e[3130613792]
[SurfaceControl] assignNativeObject: nativeObject = 0 Surface(name=null)/@0x27a6214 / android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1117 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1810 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9005 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3360 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9971 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1010 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks:809 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame:744 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run:995 
[SurfaceControl] assignNativeObject: nativeObject = 0 Surface(name=null)/@0xb548384 / android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1117 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1820 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9005 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3360 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9971 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1010 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks:809 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame:744 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run:995 
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject s[3130613920]
[SurfaceControl] nativeRelease nativeObject e[3130613920]
[ViewRootImpl@a293eaf[MainActivity]] Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1200,1920) new=(0,0,1200,1920) req=(1200,1920)8 dur=11 res=0x5 s={false 0} ch=true fn=62
[SurfaceView] windowStopped(true) false com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.at{e04ff1 VFE...C.. ........ 0,0-1164,900} of ViewRootImpl@a293eaf[MainActivity]
[ViewRootImpl@a293eaf[MainActivity]] stopped(true) old=false
```

Comment: Have you try to debug step by step? Which line of the code throw the error. What is the details of the error? For the information in output, have you used any code related maps?

Comment: Sorry, my experience with debugging best practice is very limited. I have included the debug output in its entirety as an edit to my original question (at the end). The issue I have is that it doesn't crash consistently on any of my devices but seems to on user devices, all of which are using Gallaxy Tab A10s @WendyZang-MSFT Zang - MSFT

Comment: I do not have the same device to test. Have you try to debug on Gallaxy Tab A10s?

Comment: Yes, the output above is from a debug test that exited to the 'main page' on a Gallaxy Tab A10

Comment: @Wendy Zang - MSFT I now feel as though it could be a memory issue. Is there a way to clear memory OnPause and or OnResume?

Comment: Have you set the nohistory in your code? The link below maybe helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921337/xamarin-forms-android-crash-while-taking-photo-without-exception Or it is specifical on some device. https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/901

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info @Wendy Zang - MSFT. No I don't have nohistory in my code. Reading the 2nd article it appears likely that the camera is using up all of the Device's memory. Is there away to dispose of the Camera and it's associated memory once I return to my App? Can't find any good guidance on this.

Comment: You could use the code below to clear the cache. `((ActivityManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(ActivityService)).ClearApplicationUserData();` For more details about this, you could refer to the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286373/how-to-clear-catch-data-of-my-application-programmatically-in-xamarin-android-mo