# Xamarin.Android 12 - Samsung Galaxy Tab crashes when taking images

Tags: android, image, xamarin, crash, android-12

In my app I'm taking pictures like this:

```
  public void OpenCam()
    {
        // Standard
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);

        _newFile = new Java.IO.File(Storage.Instance.TmpImageFilePath);

        intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput,
            FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Context, Context.PackageName + ".provider", _newFile));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);

        StartActivityForResult(intent, TakeImageRequest);
    }
```

after taking a picture and and confirm the taken picture with ✓ in the photo app,
**OnActivityResult** is called and I can work with the data.

This worked fine for a few years.

Now, on my **Samsung Galaxy Tab7 FE - Android 12**, **every ~third attempt fails**. The app crashes on clicking the round button to take a picture (that's the moment when the Visual Studio debugger stops). No error, no exception, OnActivityResult is not called.

`logcat`: (orange marked is my app package name)
[image]

and right before:

```
06-03 09:06:33.670  Samsung SM-T733 Info    1200    ActivityManager Process MYAPP (pid 28306) has died: prev LAST(511,287)
```

**Edit:**
Devices I could test without this problem:

- Huawei P30 lite (Android 8)
- Huawei P30 Pro ( Android 10)
- Samsung A52s 5G (Android 12)
- Huawei Mediapad M5 lite (Android 8)

Comment: Review the Android Debug `logcat` output to determine why the OS is terminating the app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/android-debug-log?tabs=windows

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't make sense of the logcat. Is there something you can say about it?

Comment: The logs shows a lot of influencing factors. We could not make sure which one. Could you check on other devices? Did this only occur on  Samsung Galaxy Tab7 FE - Android 12?

Comment: Hi @WendyZang-MSFT I just added the devices I could test. All without this problem

Comment: I guess it happened on specific device.

Comment: any ideas for troubleshooting?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce. Could you check the code on other Android 12 devices? You could use emulators to make sure if it happened on Samsung Galaxy.

Comment: I just read this post https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/901 which says that the Samsung Camera App just takes the whole memory and tries to free memory by killing my app :/ 

also tried to set NoHistory to false like in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921337/xamarin-forms-android-crash-while-taking-photo-without-exception

Comment: Let's follow the issue on GitHub.